# My Abbreviation list is gone?

Tags: lists, indexing

My MikTeX version is: 2.9
My TeXnicCenter version is: 2.02
My document is generated, everything is in their, content, references, but not my abbreviation list, though it did it yesterday and the name abbreviations is written on the page

The file:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\input{text/title}

\input{text/erklaerung}

\input{text/abstract}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname} 

\section*{\nomname}


\newcommand\oldsection{}
\let\oldsection=\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\begin{multicols*}{2} % two-column layout for abbreviations
{
\begin{flushleft}
\printnomenclature
\end{flushleft}
}
\end{multicols*} % switch back to one column after two-column layout for abbreviations

\let\section=\oldsection

\input{text/introduction}

Among other proteins, Suppressor of cytokine signaling (SOCS)\nomenclature{SOCS}{Suppressor of cytokine signaling} and Protein inhibitor of activated STAT (PIAS)\nomenclature{PIAS}{Protein inhibitor of activated STAT} as inhibitors of the JAK-STAT pathway are dampening IFN and cytokine related signaling. 

\input{text/results}

\input{text/discussion}

\end{document}
```

The error messages:

> MakeIndex> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea +
>   Thai support).
>       MakeIndex> Scanning input file filename.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
>       MakeIndex> Nothing written in filename.ind
>       MakeIndex> Transcript written in filename.ilg
>       MakeIndex> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support)
>       MakeIndex> Scanning input file nomencl.ist...done (0 entries accepted, 75 rejected).
>       MakeIndex> Scanning input file filename.nlo...done (0 entries accepted, 132 rejected).
>       MakeIndex> Overall 2 files read (0 entries accepted, 207 rejected).
>       MakeIndex> Nothing written in filename.nls
>       MakeIndex> Transcript written in filename.nlg

Seetings in Define Output:

> (La)TeX: MakeIndex:
>  path to executables:
>   MiKTeX\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe
>  command line
>       "%tm".idx -t "%tm".ilg -o "%tm".ind

Postprocessor:

> Executables: MiKTeX\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe
>  Arugments:
>   nomencl.ist -t "%tm".nlg -o "%tm".nls "%tm".nlo

I already tested instead of `makeindex.exe` `miketex-makeindex.exe`, didn't help
I tested with `bm` and `tm`, no changes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're example isn't compilable at all and a mess, actually.

Comment: The line `Scanning input file nomencl.ist...done (0 entries accepted, 75 rejected)` suggests the ist file is being treated as an input file. Did you forget the `-s` switch?

Comment: You've given your list of arguments as `nomencl.ist -t "%tm".nlg -o "%tm".nls "%tm".nlo` (where you've written the postprocessor information in your question). This list is missing `-s` at the start of it. The arguments should be `-s nomencl.ist -t "%tm".nlg -o "%tm".nls "%tm".nlo`

Answer (score 2):

Because we do not have a compiling MWE and we do not have your file `nomencl.ist` I can not test it, but with the following changing in the definition of your output profile for TeXnicCenter it should work.

- Delete the entry for the **postprocessor**
- Add `-s nomencl.ist` to the command line of **MakeIndex**

My profile definition in TeXnicCenter:

[image]

Comment: I think `nomencl.ist` is included with the `nomencl` package.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My document contains a "header" file with nearly all packages and this file. Both in total have 450 lines, excluding the "real" content in intro file an so on, I have no clue which commands you would need additionally. changing the makeindex line didn't help.